# Error al pasar un dato al servicio deleteUser (servicio no definido)

Tags: jquery, webservice, datatable, angular8

Tengo esta tabla

**datatable.component.html**

```
                        <tr *ngFor="let row of dataTable.dataRows">
                            <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                            <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
                            <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
                            <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
                            <td>{{row[4]}}</td>
                            <td>{{row[5]}}</td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-info btn-just-icon block"><i class="material-icons">block</i></a>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-warning btn-just-icon edit"><i class="material-icons">dvr</i></a>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-danger btn-just-icon remove"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

**datatable.component.ts**
en general lo que hace este componente es agregarle funcionalidad a 3 botones que se crean dinamicamente conforme el numero de registros obtenidos como se puede ver en la imagen de abajo del post.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AddUserService } from './../../services/service.index';
import { DeleteUserService } from './../../services/service.index';

declare interface DataTable {
    headerRow: string[];
    footerRow: string[];
    dataRows: string[][];
}
declare const $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-data-table-cmp',
    templateUrl: 'datatable.component.html',
    providers: [DeleteUserService]
})

export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

constructor(
  private UserService: AddUserService,
  public deleteUserService: DeleteUserService
) {}
    public dataTable: DataTable;
    @Input() public headerTable: string[];
    @Input() public footerTable: string[];
    @Input() public dataRowsTable: string[][];
    @Input() public leyenda: string[];
    user= true;
if(leyenda = "User") {
  return this.user=true;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataTable = {
      headerRow: this.headerTable,
      footerRow: this.footerTable,
      dataRows:  this.dataRowsTable
    };
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  $('#datatables').DataTable({
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "lengthMenu": [
      [10, 25, 50, -1],
      [10, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],
    responsive: true,
    language: {
      search: "_INPUT_",
      searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
    }

  });

  const table = $('#datatables').DataTable();

  // Edit record
  table.on('click', '.edit', function(e) {
    let $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    if ($($tr).hasClass('child')) {
      $tr = $tr.prev('.parent');
    }
    var data = table.row($tr).data();
    alert('You press on Row: ' + data[0] + ' ' + data[1] + ' ' + data[2] + '\'s row.');
    e.preventDefault();
  });


  // Delete a record
  table.on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
    const $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var data = table.row($tr).data();
    this.deleteUserService.deleteUser(data[0]);
    table.row($tr).remove().draw();
    e.preventDefault();
  } );

  //Like record
  table.on('click', '.block', function(e) {
    alert('Cuenta suspendida');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.card .material-datatables label').addClass('form-group');
}
}
```

> deleteUser.service.ts
>   Este es el servicio que utilizo para eliminar a un usuario por su id

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { URL_SERVICIOS } from '../../config/config';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DeleteUserService {

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

deleteUser(id_delete: number) {
  try{
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    };
    console.log('usuario borrado')
    return this.httpClient.delete(URL_SERVICIOS + `/users/${id_delete}`, httpOptions);
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}
}
```

lo que necesito es que mande la id del registro al del cual estoy precionando el boton de eliminar 
pero al ejecutar el programa ocurre este mensaje

> ERROR TypeError: "this.deleteUserService is undefined"

yo supongo que tiene que ver con el tiempo de vida de los componentes pero no se me ocurre que hacer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tienes `DeleteUserService` declarado en providers?

Comment: Deberias tener algo asi dentro de `@component({` : `providers: [`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> datatable.component.ts

Mi error era por `this` y `jQuery` ya que dentro del scope de la funcion, `this` apunta al objeto de jQuery

**La solucion fue declarar `this` en una variable fuera de jQuery (`_this`)**

```
  let _this = this;
  // Delete a record
  table.on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
    const $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var data = table.row($tr).data();
    table.row($tr).remove().draw();
    e.preventDefault();
    _this.deleteUserService.deleteUser(data[0])
    .subscribe();
  } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu error puede radicar en el **provider** del componente, angular necesita saber si ese servicio sera un proveedor, deberías de agregar el servicio en el `providers` esto esta entre las importaciones y el constructor del componente:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tu-componente',
  templateUrl: './tucomponente.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tucomponente.component.css'],
  providers: [DeleteUserService]
})
```

Y en el constructor

```
constructor(private deleteUserService: DeleteUserService) {}
```

Con esto ya deberías de poder acceder a los métodos del servicio.

Comment: acabo de colocar las modificaciones recomendadas pero el problema continua, puedo usar el servicio en funciones dentro de esta clase pero no puedo usarla dentro de ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: @Angel y si sacas el metodo de eliminar que tienes en el After y lo pones en un metodo , el cual actives desde el boton de la tabla..... ademas en tu html te faltan parenceis y tienes mal uno de los boton `<a href="javascript:void(0" 
      <a href="javascript:void(0s"`

Comment: de ese modo si funciona, ejecutandolo desde un boton pero mi duda es si puedo hacerlo dentro del after?

Comment: Si lo vas hacer dentro del after tienes que utilizar evenEmit